# Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, build-pipeline

I am trying to host a jave project. I have build the pipeline by setting up the parameters as shown in the images but the i am encountering the error saying ##[warning]Directory '/home/azureuser/myagent/.\run.cmd/5/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'. How do I fix this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to publish your jar package to build artifact 'drop'. Jar package should be in the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\target` folder. Thus, you need to use the copy file task to copy jar package from target folder, then publish the package to drop.

[image]

You could also check the log of Maven task to see the specific location of jar package.

[image]

Comment: Hi @theharpretsingh, please check you package location in Maven task. Then, configure your pipeline. If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).